# Store an object as a property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, object

I have an object in Javascript to store an image as well as some other properties such as x,y,opacity and how to draw it. When I try to store the image object as a property, it doesn't work. When I store it as a variable it does. Is there a way to store an object as a property, or is there a better way to handle this?

```
function imageClass(src){
    var image=new Image();
    image.src=src;
    this.x=0;
    this.y=0;
    this.scale=1;
    this.opacity=1;
    this.draw=function(){
        ctx.drawImage(image,this.x,this.y);
    };
}
```

When I try to put the image variable as a property, the draw function doesn't work

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of your code?

Comment: What does "doesn't work mean"? Show us some code, explain what you want it to do, and describe what it actually does.

Comment: What does `this` refer to in your code?

Comment: you have to show how you call `imageClass`

Comment: Just guessing, but it looks like you might have a scope issue. Inside the `draw` function, `this` is probably not referring to the same object as where you define `this.image` (depending on how you are calling this.draw). Your draw image function may be working with `this.x` and `this.y` being 0 because the drawImage is converting a `null` or `undefined` to a 0. therefore it works. If you chagned the `this.x` to a non-zero number, I'm guessing it would still draw at 0 and not where you specified. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Phil if he instantiates the object with the `new` keyword, then `this` will refer to a `imageClass` object.

Comment: Just guessing in the absence of code, but if you decide to do `this.image = new Image();`, then you have to use `this.image` *everywhere* throughout, including in the call to `ctx.drawImage` inside the `draw` function.